# Detecting UINavigationBar Subviews Type in iPhone App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, custom-controls, uinavigationbar

I have been trying to customize a navigation bar in an iPhone app. I was trying to use a subclass of navigationbar and use the layout subviews method to actually manipulate the views that I required. Right now, I am getting the list of the subviews but I have no idea how to detect which subview is a barbutton or which is the title view. All I can see in their description is that it is a UINavigationItem and and some additional information.
Need some help on this!

Thanks!

Comment: start adding your code used to detect the subviews...

Comment: its the simple approach of getting the subviews and iterating through the array to get to my particular view:
<code>for (id view in self.subviews) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIBarButtonItem class]]) {
    }
}</code>
But I need to check the view for title by setting the title of the viewcontroller not the title view.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (id view in self.subviews) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIBarButtonItem class]]) {
        // subview is UIBarButtonItem
    }
    // etc...
}
```

If the goal is to manipulate the size of the title, I think you should instead set the `titleView` of `UINavigationItem`. This must be done in the `UIViewController` that you push onto your `UINavigationController`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Play around with the frame of the UILabel to 
    // achieve the effect you are going for
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:self.navigationItem.titleView.frame];
    label.text = @"Title text";
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Oblik-Bold" size:18];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [label sizeToFit];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = label;
}
```

If you don't want to do this in every `UIViewController` you could make a base class that implements the feature and all your `UIViewController`s inherit from.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. It works good for the BarButtonItem but what If I want to check other subviews like the title? Apparently, from what I have seen, and I am not an expert, when you set a title to the navigation bar, it cannot be detected yet assigning label to the titleview can be detected. What should be the possible solution for that?

Comment: I have not been able locate where you can access the title of the navigationbar. The UINavigationItems you mention are not interface elements, but rather what you have on your navigation stack. What is your purpose for subclassing? There are quite elaborate possibilities for customizing UINavigationBar without subclassing.

Comment: Actually, the problem that I am coming across is that I need to change the frame of the of title of the navigation bar. Since I am using a custom navigation bar so the title usually tilts away from its original position or truncates the text for no reason at all. So I was thinking that since I am using the subviews anyway, why not change its frame accordingly so I can get a better view. I hope you are getting what I am saying.

P.S. I would have had given you a +1 but I dont have sufficient points and that is not the answer I am looking for right now.

Comment: I understand your problem. I have edited my answer to give you an alternative solution. I'm not sure if it's possible to manipulate the frame of default view. Probably not what you were looking for, but it's as far as I can help you.

Comment: Yes, you are right. This is a possible solution but in my case I need to do this through setting the title and not using the titleview. I have edited the question in which I stated it to be a category, infact it was a subclass. Apologies and Thanks!

Comment: @PaulHunter Thank you for you help. Its a +1 from me but I do not have enough points for that. Thanks mate!